# Does runway center lighting increase runway lifetime?

Tags: runways, airport-lighting

I wonder if the centerline lighting helps add a few more years to the runway, especially with heavy aircraft like A350/A380, in addition of being helpful for landing and takeoff?

---

My question is based on a [recent reading](http://www.bangaloreaviation.com/2016/09/bengaluru-mumbai-airports-runway-closures-to-impact-passengers.html) where this question was asked:

> Why did the airport operator BIAL not plan for centre line lighting 
>   at the time of runway construction?

Update - From what little I garnered, understood and logic applied, it seems/feels that a centre line lightning would make when the airplane lands with more precision than otherwise. This would mean that the aircraft doesn't go all over the place and while some specific parts of the runaway would be more stressed, others wouldn't. I know there are a mixture of narrow and wide-body aircraft but still it should make life of the runaway, at least on the edges more. Also maintenance of the runaway should be a tad easier as perhaps only some specific parts of the runaway would need more maintenance . I may be totally off in my assessment hence asking here.

Update 2 - From the comments then, what is the centreline lightning useful for ? Also if there any pictures which explains it as well would be useful. I know there are lights on left and right of the aircraft for it to know that there is a runaway here. What does centreline lightning bring to the table ?

Comment: The question seems to make most sense to me if one of the works planned for the runway closure the author complains about is _installation_ of centerline lights -- even though it doesn't say so anywhere else in the article.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by lifetime. Lighting does not increase the strenght of runway. Lighting can help if higher catergory of operation is required. Lighting may not be installed from the start because there is no need to do so. So which aspect of lifetime you need to know?

Comment: My reading of that article is that the runway had to be closed in 2012 for surface repairs and will be closed again in 2017 to add lighting, but there's no link mentioned between the two issues.

Comment: @mins I updated my query, maybe you can shed some more light on the subject.

Comment: My raw assumption would be that general weather conditions(airport's climate) and traffic volumes would be the top factors by far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, runway centreline lights do not increase runway lifetime, and it is not their purpose to do so.